# Will the push notifications for the MFP7.1 apps in iOS devices stop working from 31 March, 2021?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have come to know that Apple has mandated to use HTTP/2 based Push Notifications for APNS from 31 March, 2021. HTTP/2 protocol for APNS has been added in IBM Mobile First version 8 and not supported in MFP7.1.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=uzyxiriy

My question is, as my already live application is present in Apple Store created using MFP7.1, will the push notifications generated from that application will not been delivered to the iOS devices from 31 March, 2021?

If yes, will there be any very quick solution except upgrading to MFP8 and which we can implement in 1-2 days in our MFP7.1 app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any update on this please?

Comment: Here's what I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911